# Actualizar una tabla con otra tabla con un trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, update

Intente con lo siguiente pero me da error

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERCION_RELACION_PROV_PROD AFTER INSERT ON PRODUCTO 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE Relacion_Prov_Prod INNER JOIN Producto 
SET Relacion_Prov_Prod.ID_Prod = Producto.ID_Prod 
WHERE Relacion_Prov_Prod.ID_Rel_P_P = Producto.ID_Prod ;
```

Es una tabla relacionada y necesito guardar la primary key de la Tabla "Producto" en el campo "ID_Prod" de la tabla "Relacion_Prov_Prod".

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERCION_RELACION_PROV_PROD AFTER INSERT ON PRODUCTO 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE Relacion_Prov_Prod INNER JOIN Producto 
ON Relacion_Prov_Prod.ID_Rel_P_P = Producto.ID_Prod 
SET Relacion_Prov_Prod.ID_Prod = Producto.ID_Prod ;
```

También intente hacerlo de esta forma,pero igual no funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Todo esta correcto, solamente necesite borrar el "BEGIN", que por algún motivo que desconozco, no permite crear el trigger

Comment: Para que la comunidad te ayudará mejor, hubiera sido ideal que adjuntaras el error que te salía.

Comment: Ademas de apoyar lo que @Aprendiz te ha sugerido... También hacer notar que el *BEGIN* siempre tiene que ser cerrado con un *END*, fue por eso el error que tenias al principio. Pero si hubieras usado mas de una instrucción dentro de tu trigger era mas que necesario usarlos y establecer un delimitador.